# Xcode can't generate code coverage for prebuilt framework

Tags: ios, frameworks, code-coverage

Can anyone help with this problem:

- I have an iOS framework A (written in Swift) and be built to A.framwork.
- I have an application B, which uses framework A. There is a Unit test target BTests. Now I want to generate code coverage when run BTests, which call some function in framework A. I haven't found any method to support that: the generated Coverage.profdata never contains coverage information for framework A.

Step to reproduce: as the description above.

- Create an Xcode project that builds framework A (can be dynamic or static).
- Create another Xcode project, which has application B, and test target BTests.
- B includes A
- Turn on gather code coverage.
- Run unit test (BTests).
- Check generated Coverage.profdata and see no coverage information for framework A.